# How to define JSON schema for object that holds Properties object?

Tags: json, jsonschema

I need to create a JSON schema for object that will include java Properties object as one of its properties.
The nested Properties object will be simply list of key=value. Both key and value are of type string.
I failed to find any docs that describe how to define the schema that includes 2 new types.

shall it be something like:

```
{
"type": "object",
"name": "MyObj",
"properties": {
    "prop1": {
        "type": "string",
        "description": "prop1",
        "required": true
    },
    "props": {
        "type": "array",
        "items": {
            "type": "object"
            "properties": {
                "key": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "description": "key",
                    "required": true
                },
                "value": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "description": "the value",
                    "required": true
                }
            }
            "description": "the value",
            "required": true
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The schema you have written (assuming the commas are fixed) describes data of the form:

```
{
    "prop1": "Some string property goes here",
    "props": [
        {"key": "foo", "value": "bar"},
        {"key": "foo2", "value": "bar2"},
        ...
    ]
}
```

If this is what you wanted, then you are already finished.

However, I do wonder why you are using key/value pairs in an array, when you could use a JSON object with string keys instead.  Using the `additionalProperties` keyword, you could have a schema:

```
{
    "type": "object",
    "name": "MyObj",
    "properties": {
        "prop1": {
            "type": "string",
            "description": "prop1"
        },
        "props": {
            "type": "object",
            "additionalProperties": {
                "type": "string",
                "description": "string values"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This describes a data format like:

```
{
    "prop1": "Some string property goes here",
    "props": {
        "foo": "bar",
        "foo2": "bar2"
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to impose constraints on the key, you can also use patternProperties with additionalProperties: false. You can use "pattern" to impose constraints on the value as well.

Answer (score 0):

At [W3 schools (JSON Syntax)](http://www.w3schools.com/json/json_syntax.asp) you can read how the array should be defined.

There is no schema like the xsd for xml, however i've found an approach [on json-schema.org](http://json-schema.org/). If you are able to, i'll advice to youse google-GSON [library for JSON](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/). You could Store key Value as `"id" : "value"` and build only one object, containing all requieed pairs:

```
{ "lang" : "EN" , "color" : "red" }
```

Your posted model is incorect, you can check it [on jsonlint.com](http://jsonlint.com/)
Here is a working version, i'm not sure if the modell is as expected.

```
{
    "type": "object",
    "name": "MyObj",
    "properties": [
        {
            "prop1": {
                "type": "string",
                "description": "prop1",
                "required": true
            },
            "props": {
                "type": "array",
                "items": {
                    "type": "object",
                    "properties": {
                        "key": {
                            "type": "string",
                            "description": "key",
                            "required": true
                        },
                        "value": {
                            "type": "string",
                            "description": "the value",
                            "required": true
                        }
                    },
                    "description": "the value",
                    "required": true
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I fixed few commas that were missing, but I guess what I was trying to ask was : is there more common way to define java Properties-like member in JSON schema or should I stay with an array?