# Validating a complex json in python

Tags: python, json, validation

we have a json file, which I try to validate with jsonschema in python3.

But I don't know, how to describe ou format for a schema.
The json looks like:

```
{     "some_name": {
        "Type": "some_type",
        "Path": "a file path",
        "Default": "",
        "Descr": [
            "some text which describe",
            "the purpose of this entry"
        ],
        "Value": ""
    },
    "some_name2": {
        "Type": "another_type",
        "Path": "a file path ",
        "Default": "",
        "Descr": [
            "another text",
            "which describe the purpose"
        ],
        "Value": ""
    }
}
```

I don't know how to describe "some_name" and "some_name2" in the schema. All the examples I found are always like ""description" : {"type" : "string"}", but "some_name" in my case has no name.

I tried and searched a lot, but can't find a explanation for my case.
Any help appreciated

Comment: Consider referring to examples such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19362267/how-to-define-json-schema-for-object-that-holds-properties-object) to help you get started.